# How to substitue better in Cheetah templates

Tags: python, cheetah

Given the following Cheetah template

```
#filter None
{data:[
#for $person in $persons
{naam: "#if $person.lastname==None then '' else $person.lastname.replace('"', '\\"')#}, 
#end for
]}
#end filter
```

That's quite a mouthful for replacing " with \\"

Anyone has an easier/shorter way of writing this expression?

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Cheetah, but maybe this works:

```
{naam: "#$person.lastname and $person.lastname.replace('"', '\\"')#},
```

Comment: Nope, the #if ... then ... else ...# seems to be evaluated by Cheetah and not by Python